# Displaying Wordpress plugins quicker

Tags: php, wordpress

on my wordpress page, I have like 7 plugins, and it takes like 20 seconds for page to load up and then all of the data gets displayed. However, 1 plugin loads pretty fast, is there a way to make that plugin would get displayed as soon as it gets loaded? For example, 1st gets displayed, 2nd gets displayed, etc. every 3 seconds instead of waiting all 20 seconds to get displayed everything at once. I am using twenty sixteen theme and the plugins work like this: once wp page gets loaded plugins gets activated, that triggers to run python programs through ssh, python program scrapes some data from the websites and it gets displayed were wp plugin's shortcode is placed on website.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you want to load the page without plugins at first and load the plugins separately, so, you will need to write support code for sending a single plugin to a page, remove the plugin loading code from server-side page load and when the plugin container is loaded, send asynchronous requests for each individual plugin from client-side. Off course, you will need to prepare a list of plugins to know what you need to load.